# Typeset a dialogue?

Tags: packages, formatting, line-breaking, paragraphs

I need to typeset a dialogue in LaTeX, it's for a translation assignment. The original dialogue does something like this:

```
- I found it, I told him.
My finger was in the book, where George Best's autograph was. My da was
sitting in his chair.
- Did you? he said. - Good man. What?
- What?
- What did you find?
- The autograph, I told him.
He was messing.
```

I would like to keep that formatting without resorting to `\\` and such. I found the `dialogue` package on CTAN, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly what is it that you want to avoid in your code? I see no reason for not letting LaTeX know where you want your line breaks. What's wrong with `\\\`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Really depends on how long you need this to go for and how fussy you are. Based on your description I'd define something like

```
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\setlength\parskip{1ex plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\newcommand\X{\par\noindent---~}
```

and write

```
\X I found it, I told him.

My finger was in the book, where George Best's autograph was. My da was
sitting in his chair.

\X Did you? he said. ---~Good man. What?
\X What?
\X What did you find?
\X The autograph, I told him.

He was messing.
```

No need to be fancy.

Comment: The text is only ~2 pages long, and I'm not very picky with the final results. I was only curious off the alternatives. But the `\setlength`-parts above, can they be applied only to a certain area of the document?

Comment: Sure! But best to do it when you're between paragraphs to avoid odd surprises.