# Incompatible versions of luatex problem

Tags: memoir, makeindex, idxlayout

When I run the code below, I get an error about

```
 Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.
```

Oddly, it says the error is on line 174, but there are not that many lines in the code. I get the same error with the `imakeidx` package.

I am not using luatex at all, and don't know where that came from.

MWE starts here.

```
\documentclass[11pt, statementpaper]{memoir}
% \let\providelength\relax
\title{Interesting words}
\author{Peter Flom}

 \usepackage[columns=3]{idxlayout}

%\usepackage{imakeidx}[2012/05/09]
%\makeindex[columns=3]

%% A convenience command, for typesetting the
%% word and pronunciation

%\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} (#2)\par}}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\medskip\noindent{\Large\textbf{#1} \normalsize{#2} \par}}



%\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\normalfont\scshape #1}
\newcommand{\sclabel}[1]{\leavevmode{\normalfont\scshape #1}}
%% Less spacing around lists
\firmlists

\newcommand{\quotesep}{\rule{3in}{1pt}{\hfill}}

\newcommand{\quotefull}{\epigraphwidth 3.5in
             \epigraphrule 0pt}


%From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182869/typesetting-a-dialogue-paragraphs-or-something-else
\newenvironment{dialogue}{\list{}{\itemsep=\parskip \topsep=\parskip \parsep=\parskip}}{\endlist}

\makeindex

\begin{document}


\printindex

\bibliography{c:/writing/references}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

EDIT  I am using MikTeX 2.9.

EDIT here is the log file

```
4"
Startup Folder: C:\Writing

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: MWEAug14.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file MWEAug14.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file MWEAug14.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file MWEAug14.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   makeindex.exe "MWEAug14.idx"
Startup Folder: C:\Writing

This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning input file MWEAug14.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected).
Nothing written in MWEAug14.ind.
Transcript written in MWEAug14.ilg.


Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "MWEAug14.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Writing

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6100 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(MWEAug14.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\memoir\memoir.cls"
Document Class: memoir 2020/03/25 v3.7k configurable book, report, article docu
ment class
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\iftex\iftex.sty"
) ("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\memoir\mem11.clo
") ("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\array.sty
")
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\dcolumn.sty"
)
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\delarray.sty
")
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\tabularx.sty
") (C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\textcase\textcase.sty))

("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\idxlayout\idxlayou
t.sty"
(C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty)
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions
.sty"
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.st
y")
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds
.sty")
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\kvsetke
ys.sty"
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infware
rr.sty")
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmd
s.sty"
("C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluate
x.sty"

! Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined.

See the ifluatex package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.174     }
           %
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on MWEAug14.log.
```

END OF LOG FILE

I have to go out, I will look at this more tomorrow

Comment: Exactly which package versions are you using? If I run your MWE through `pdflatex` from an up to date TeXLIve 2020 I have no issues at all. Note that those bibliography lines are probably not relevant to the problem and the `c:/...` part is something we don't have access to anyways.

Comment: Also make sure to check that you don't have some local copies of packages laying around. Had one recently that was using TL2020 and was loading a 2012 `siunitx` with it. Didn't go well

Comment: How do I tell if I have local copies of packages?

Comment: If you're using miktex the first step is of course to make sure your miktex is fully up to date in miktex user mode, and if applicable also in miktex admin mode.

Comment: You can find local packages by looking in the log, not the filtered log your editor might provide the actual log. Then look for packages with unusual paths to them, for example `./name.sty` indicates that you're loading something from the same folder as the tex file

Comment: @daleif Thanks.  I just got a new CD from TUG so I will try to installt the new version this weekend

Comment: If you have the internet for it I'd recommend installing it online instead. It will have to be updated anyways.

Comment: note the log file which you have not shown will show you _which_ file line 174 is on, it would also show if you have any local files causing incompatibilities

Comment: I will add the log file to my question

Comment: Tracing the `()` in the posted log, it appears that it's not liking line 147 of the `ifluatex` package, which is loaded by the `etexcmds` package, which is loaded by the `kvsetkeys` package, which is loaded by the `kvoptions` package, which is loaded by the `idxlayout` package.

Comment: you have a very old latex (2016) which is odd as normally miktex would update it for you, I don't use miktex but you should be able to tell it to update everything and rebuild the formats from the miktex console.

Comment: I tried to update it over the web and it bombed.  More tomorrow.